# Use TimeOfDay in dart

Tags: flutter, dart, time

Writing some dart code, is there an equivalent to Flutter's [TimeOfDay](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TimeOfDay-class.html) class (A value representing a time during the day, independent of the date that day might fall on or the time zone)?

Should I use DateTime with only the hours and minutes?

Comment: There is no copy of it in pure Dart. You can use whatever class you want or need to use. It's up to use as the programmer. If using a `DateTime` works for you then use that. If `TimeOfDay` works better, then copy the Flutter implementation or write your own.